# React Native Firebase delete user data

Tags: firebase, react-native

How can I make a function that deletes all todos that the user has?

This is a function that I am calling

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evR3D.png

this is on a button press function call

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsbY2.png

And this is end result error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6RnE.png

Comment: It's helpful if you paste code rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

`delete` is not an available function on a collection. Deleting an entire collection is not recommended, and thus you have to iterate through the documents and delete them individually. From the official Firebase documentation:

> To delete an entire collection or subcollection in Cloud Firestore, retrieve all the documents within the collection or subcollection and delete them. If you have larger collections, you may want to delete the documents in smaller batches to avoid out-of-memory errors. Repeat the process until you've deleted the entire collection or subcollection.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#web_2

To get all of the documents in the collection, you can do this:

```
const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection(COLLECTION_NAME).get()
```

And then you can iterate through `snapshot.docs` and delete each one. Keep in mind that each `delete` call will be async, so unless you don't care about when everything finishes, you may want to use `Promise.all` or something to keep track of when all of the async actions finish.